# Execute Lua script in java?

Tags: java, lua

So I’m learning java right now and built a GUI which functions how I want. But I need a way I can call a lua script within my java script. I’m pretty good with lua and have used the code below in lua to launch another lua script externally through the cmd.

os.execute(‘start “Data save”  cmd /k “cd ‘ .. path .. ‘ & ‘  .. r_path .. ‘bin\luae.exe testscript.lua & exit “‘)

Me being new to java was researching and was getting really confused. But the reason behind this is I’m making an external dialog for a game that only reads lua code. So the plan is to get the information from the dialog and execute the lua file with the new dialog info then generate a new lua file with this information with :write() in lua.

I just need to be able to execute a lua file within java with arguments that’s it.

Comment: java...or javascript???

Comment: I think just java.

Comment: you should know what language you're using. Otherwise how can we help you?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://github.com/darmie/LuaJ

Comment: Im using Java and I looked into LuaJ but confused on where to install it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the answer you're looking for, but you can run shell commands in Java with the `Runtime` class which is already included in the `java.lang` package, and its `exec(String cmd)` method is generally a good `os.execute` substitute in java itself.

**Usage**

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec('start "Data save" cmd /k "cd ' .. path .. ' & ' .. r_path .. 'bin\luae.exe testscript.lua & exit "')
    }
}
```

You might want to look more into the `Runtime` class in general.

But if you're literally looking to interpret Lua in Java then I heard [LuaJ](http://www.luaj.org/luaj/3.0/README.html) is a good option.